# URL configuration

Tags: python, django, url

how can two URL point to the same function, one with parameter and one without, both should show the index page, second one pass a parameter?
But the second one is incorrect, it gives me an error when i try to pass a parameter.

```
(r'^$', 'index'),
(r'^/(?P<jobtype>.*)/$', 'index'),
```

Thanks in Advance

the whole url :

```
urlpatterns+= patterns('job.views', 
 url(r'^$', 'index'),
 (r'/(?P<jobtype>.*)/$', 'index'),
 (r'^profile/addJob/$', 'addJob'),
 (r'editjob/(?P<jobid>.*)/$', 'editJob'),
 )
```

the error is

Page not found (404)
   Request Method: GET 
   Request URL: 127.0.0.1:8000/reng%C3%B8ring/ 
I try to pass a string paramter "rengøring"

Comment: Can you post the whole url pattern and the code of the view?
And, what error do you get?

Comment: Show us your view function as also.

Comment: just add the whole url pattern and error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the `jobtype` parameter of the index view optional:

```
def index(request, jobtype=None):
    ...
    if jobtype is not None:
        do_something()
    ...
    return render_to_response('index.html', locals())
```

Comment: I hav that function, but the problem is django couldn't find the url pattern with a parameter

Comment: Try to make the URLPattern like this: `(r'^/(?P<jobtype>\w+)/$', 'index'),`

Comment: can still not find the url pattern :(

Comment: Ahh, remove the trailing slash at the beginning of the URL pattern: `(r'^(?P<jobtype>\w+)/$', 'index')`

Comment: thanks it looks liek this problem is solved, but new problem appear :(

Comment: i have a Dansih letter "ø" in the parameter, which give me an error

ValueError at /rengøring/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'reng\xf8ring'

Comment: I guess you can use [SlugFields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) in order to standardize the URLs (and avoid such Unicode characters). You can also play more with the regex (in order to allow such characters), but slugification is the cleanest solution.